# How to call viewForHeaderInSection Function Manually in iOS Xcode in Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to call below function Manually in iOS Xcode, Because I used custom header and when I got to portrait to landscape then the view will display badly.

So, suggest me how to call `viewForHeaderInSection` when I go to portrait to landscape mode.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `viewForHeaderInSection`. The proper solution is to fix the layout code/constraints in your header view.

Comment: How can i manage it, Can give one example thank you.

Answer (score 0):

viewForHeaderInSection calls when table is drawing so the only way is to reload table.

Comment: There is no need to reload the table view.